# How can I connect my javafx application to my sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to connect to a database when I run my application I am getting the error "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection string contains a badly formed name or value".

I have tried changing some of the variables around but cannot figure out where my error is. Can anyone help?

```
        try{
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());
            String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://[myservername];databaseName=[databasename];user=[enteruserdbhere];password[enterpasswordhere];";

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

            conn.close();
            statement.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the '[]' brackets from the connection string.
The link below shows examples of connection strings for jdbc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the brackets [ ] for your connection URL.

```
String server = "localhost";
String dbName = "myDB";
String username = "root";
String pwd = "";

String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://server;databaseName=dbName;user=username;password=pwd;";
```

Also import your jdbc driver to the project as well us in the Connection.java file